# How do I view the questions I have protected?

Tags: discussion, protected-questions

Is there any way to view the questions I have protected, or get statistics on the number of protected questions by user?

Comment: Thanks @bluefeet, could find this via search for some reason.

Comment: You'll have to query it the data explorer, it's not on profile... yet

Comment: @bluefeet is there an open feature request to add this information to your profile?  Or should I write one.

Comment: There have been several on MSE - here is one - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269628/please-add-the-list-of-questions-un-protected-to-the-profile-page